# Unknown tags and undefined functions in JSP fragments

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, jsp-fragments

I imported a web project build in JSP, which I am relatively new to. I got some errors in `WEB-INF/includes/components` that I am unable to resolve.

Some `.jspf` files show me errors such as at that line:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(view.parent.views) > 1}">
```

the error is:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- The function fn:length is 
 undefined
- Unknown tag (c:if).
```

I also get errors like `The function fn:length is undefined` errors for `fn:length`.

I followed up with other questions and made sure that `standard.jar` and `jstl-1.2.jar` are included in my build path. Moreover, `WEB-INF/includes/taglibs.jspf` has the following :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if I add the following at the beginning of my JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="nav" uri="/WEB-INF/taglibs/navigation.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

This is a working answer for now, but I think the best answer would be the one that tells how it can be sufficient to include the lines above in `taglibs.jspf`, instead of having them in every `.jsp` file.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced same problem. I added a base.jspf file and referred it on the top of the file:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/includes/base.jspf" %>
```

That file contains

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```